# List directories first with MinGW ls

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, ls, mingw

I have recently started using MinGW instead of Cygwin on my Windows 7 machine, and I am having a little issue with MinGW's `ls`.  In Cygwin, `ls` has a `--group-directories-first` option that, obviously, causes directories to be listed before other file types.  However, MinGW doesn't seem to have this option, and I can't find a substitute for it.  Does one exist?

Answer (score 1):

This comes under the heading “a substitute for it”.  The following script will approximately emulate the behavior of `ls –l` with the difference that it groups subdirectories at the beginning of each directory listing.

```
#!/bin/sh -
sort_ls_output()
{
    sed -n -e '1s/^/1#/p' -e '1n' \
        -e 's/^/#/' -e 's/^#d/2#d/' -e 's/^#/3#/' -e p \
        | cat -n | sort -n -k2 -k1 | sed 's/[^#]*#//'
}

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    ls -l | sort_ls_output
else
    for arg
    do
        echo
        if [ -d "$arg" ]
        then
            echo "${arg}:"
            ls -l "$arg" | sort_ls_output
        else
            ls -l "$arg"
        fi
    done
fi
```

It is a rough cut. 
It doesn’t handle individual ordinary files (non-directories) on the command line the same way as `ls –l` does, and it doesn’t handle options (e.g., `–a`) at all.